# Configure emacs to import using relative paths by default

Tags: javascript, typescript, emacs

I'm using emacs doom. When editing .ts typescript file, emacs can automatically import module but emacs import using absolut path

ex:

```
import { GetUser } from 'src/auth/decorator';
```

what I want is import using relative path not absolute. so What I want is

```
import { GetUser} from '../auth/decorator';
```

Why I want this?
because end to end test with jest failed my test if im import module using absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Tide](https://github.com/ananthakumaran/tide) you can change the user preferences for module imports like this:

```el
  (setq-default tide-user-preferences '(:importModuleSpecifierPreference "relative" :includeCompletionsForModuleExports t :includeCompletionsWithInsertText t :allowTextChangesInNewFiles t))
```

(requires restart of Emacs Doom)